# How to avoid locking problems while disabling/enabling triggers in a PostgreSQL function?

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Whenever I try to disable a trigger from within a function, I get following error:

```
ERROR:  cannot ALTER TABLE "datace" because it is being used by active queries in this session
```

It seems logical that tables are locked for ALTER TABLE command while used for reading writing by some function. But how should I disable/enable some trigger from that function then?

What I want to do is to update a column that should be protected from updates from outside the function. I thought this should be done through DISABLE/ENABLE trigger, but if this should be done some other way (or is not possible at all in PostgreSQL), I would be glad for such an answer too.

Comment: So you have a `BEFORE|AFTER UPDATE ... FOR EACH ROW` trigger and within the procedure it executes, you want to `UPDATE` the same table again, protecting against recursion? If so: Show us your use case - explain what problem you're trying to solve. Usually these problems are better solved by modifying `NEW` in-place, but there are exceptions.

Comment: @CraigRinger: you are probably right. I have a big function (about 400 code rows) with several updates, nothing I could easily post here or rewrite to a NEW modification within a trigger procedure. I considered making it a trigger function for insert/update on the table, but that would slow everything too much, and since it is not crucial for consistence, I'd prefer to call it just once in a time. I'll reconsider this (and probably completely change the design) and then I'll update my question to reflect the current state.

Comment: Well, if it's a case of trying to avoid recursive trigger calls, PostgreSQL doesn't really have anything conveniently built-in for that. Search Stack Overflow for a variety of workarounds.